# Nevron Open Vision for .NET - need feedback

Tags: c#, .net, mono, cross-platform, nevron

I'm considering that platform for cross platform (Windows/Mac) development. How mature is it? Any experience?

I'm especially interested in GUI development as I haven't had any issues running my non GUI .Net code on Mono.

Answer (score 3):

Disclosure: I work for Nevron.

Although Nevron Open Vision (NOV) has not been on the market for a long time, it has been internally developed for more than 7 years, so the code base is actually very mature, well tested and profiled for performance.

We were able to achieve better cross-platform operational results than any other Windows/Mac toolkit (QT, wxWidgets etc.). Futhermore NOV is used as basis for our end-user product line called Nevron Office, which exposes the heavy controls developed with NOV (like Text Editor, Diagram etc.) as end-user products. Latest versions of NOV feature transparent support for retina displays on Mac, high-resolutions on Windows etc.

We have big plans for NOV and by the end of the year we hope to release Chart, Scheduler and Grid components too, adding to the already existing UI Toolkit, Text Editor, Diagram, Gauge and Barcode. In this way we hope to provide a real end-to-end platform for cross-platform development that contains all essential components for RAD cross-platform development.

New versions of NOV will be distributed as portable libraries, meaning that your UI code that is based on NOV can be a portable library too! This will ease deployment and testing tremendously, since you can develop on Windows and just copy the dlls in Mac.

On the interaction side we will add touch support for the entire range of controls and develop feature limited hosts for iOS and Android. We are also closely monitoring the developments in the WebAssembly specification and hope to be the first vendor to provide a feature complete suite for it, as soon as browsers are able to run C# code.

So stepping on the NOV train today offers many advantages for your future development, including hassle free deployment to Windows/Mac and other OSs that we will try to support, ready-to-use UI controls and libraries and last but not least a well tested and stable environment for development that has been tested by thousands of end-users of Nevron Office.